# How to attach this wooden beam to concrete blocks

Tags: wood, outdoor, concrete-block

I want to attach a wooden beam to a hollow concrete block to use as one side of a washing line.

How should I do that?
Are there any attachments or fixings that I should use?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How permanent do you want it to be?

Comment: permanent - no plans to take it down.

Comment: Have you considered putting the post in the middle of the hollow blocks and filling with concrete?

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn’t - that block could come loose with the pull of a load of wet washing.

I would sink a tube or the wooden post further into the ground.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a pair of toggle anchors like [these](https://www.mcmaster.com/toggle-anchors/for-use-in%7Econcrete/). (*No affiliation with the manufacturer or vendor, just the first one I could find that matched what I was looking for.*)

If those are hollow all the way down, you could make your own version of that anchor by drilling holes through the post & block, inserting a piece of threaded rod through the hole, slipping a couple of large washers on the block side & screwing a nut on. (Reach your hand down through the hole in the block to reach the bottom one first then work your way up to the top.) Then add a washer & nut on the rod on the wood side and tighten. Instead of all-thread, you could use a carriage bolt or regular bolt, too. You would want to be sure to use galvanized or other weather protected hardware for this for outdoor use.

Alternatively, do the same thing with your clothes line as was done with the fence post next to it: Put the post *in* the hole in the block and fill the block with concrete. Additionally, cut a couple of pieces of rebar several feet longer than the height of the wall, drop 2 into each hole for the next block or two, drive them into the ground below the wall, then fill those holes with concrete, too.

Answer (score 1):

The wall seems a bit unstable with a high forward lean already... I'd suggest fixing the wall first before placing more stress on it. One person mentioned filling the block with concrete and rebar, which is a great idea, along with putting the post down in the ground a couple feet to add strength. Thru bolts are going to be the strongest, and there is also, concrete epoxy's you can use that work well with threaded rod that give very good strength. Whatever choice you make, keep in mind the tension and leverage from the poll and line will be much stronger than just linier stress, it will pull the wall over at some point if you don't address that issue first.